# ifthenelse equal string comparison fails

Tags: conditionals, strings, comparison

I am trying to fix some problems with the accessibility.sty package from www.babs.gmxhome.de

There is one string comparison which always results to false, i.e. the language code definition will not be executed.

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\string german}}{\gdef\LanguageCode{/Lang(DE)}}{}%
```

Now if I try

```
\message{#1}
\message{\string german}
```

The output when compiling a document will be:

german german

I am really lost, why #1 and the string `german` do not compare to true here... What could be the reason?

Comment: Why have you got `\string` here? That gives a catcode-12  ('other') `g` and then catocde-11 ('letter') `erman`. I have a feeling you are imagining that the two arguments are the same just because the letters look identical when you typeset them.

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand your comment. Afaik \string takes a token and returns a string of characters, no?!

Comment: @nbd: Better use `xstring` package for example

Comment: I tried, i.e. message{#1}, \IfStrEq{#1}{\string german}{message{moo}}{} which results in output "german". I just don't get this

Comment: Can you show *how* you use this? It's important to know what argument you're passing to `\equal` as `#1`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `\ifthenelse` test does a token-based comparison. Thus when you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\string german}}
    {TRUE}
    {FALSE}%
}
\begin{document}

\foo{german}

\end{document}
```

what happens is that `\string` is applied to the *first token* it sees, in this case a `g`. Comparing the two results, they are not the same: one has one non-letter then five letters, the second has six letters. Typesetting those two cases is different: `g` with category code 12 ('other') typesets the same glyph as `g` with category code 11 ('letter'), so the two look the same.

There are various approaches to doing true 'string' comparisons in TeX. With a modern TeX engine, by far the easiest is to use `\pdfstrcmp` or equivalent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{german}=0 %
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {TRUE}
    {FALSE}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\foo{german}

\end{document}
```

This does do a string comparison, ignoring category codes. If you want to stick with `\ifthenelse` but can assume e-TeX then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{german}}}
    {TRUE}
    {FALSE}%
}
\begin{document}

\foo{german}

\end{document}
```

will work as `\detokenize` makes its *entire* argument into a string.

Another approach without needing anything other than classical TeX primitives is to use something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\@tempa{#1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempa
    \def\@tempb{german}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
       \aftergroup\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \aftergroup\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  \endgroup
    {TRUE}
    {FALSE}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\foo{german}

\end{document}
```

using the fact that `\@onelevel@sanitize` also converts things to strings.

Of course, if you know that the input will be something sensible, there's no real need to use any detokenization at all

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{german}}
    {TRUE}
    {FALSE}%
}
\begin{document}

\foo{german}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this insightful and detailed explanation. Indeed, just leaving out \string is sufficient, since the input is already (or can assumed to be) sensible. I really was under the impression that "german" would be considered as one token. Again, thanks!

Comment: @ndbd Are you perhaps a programmer is some other language (C?): TeX's idea of a 'token' tends to confuse such people, as it's not really the same concept.

Comment: Plenty of experience in OCaml, C, some python... Yes. TeX is certainly different :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add another simple way of making a string-based choice in plain TeX without the need for additional packages. It makes use of the TeX macro expansion and uses `\csname ... \endcsname` to build a macro name.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
% define macros that are executed for every given string
\def\setlang@english{\gdef\LanguageCode{/Lang(EN)}}
\def\setlang@german{\gdef\LanguageCode{/Lang(DE)}}
\def\setlang@dutch{\gdef\LanguageCode{/Lang(NL)}}
\newcommand{\setlang}[1]{
  % call the macro corresponding to argument #1
  \csname setlang@#1\endcsname
}
\makeatother

% test the macro
\begin{document}
  \setlang{english}
  \LanguageCode
  \setlang{dutch}
  \LanguageCode
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use package `etoolbox` (which works with XeLaTeX), here is an MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\language}{german}
\ifdefstring{\language}{german}{German}{Other}
\\

\renewcommand{\language}{english}
\ifdefstring{\language}{german}{German}{Other}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: german]

The advantage of using `\ifdefstring` is that, you can leave the curly braces empty to "do **nothing**"

```latex
\ifdefstring
{\language}{german}
{German}
{} %% do nothing
```

Comment: What if the second argument "german" is white space ({}) ? How would you make it work? (I tried using {} but it doesn't work)

Comment: @Peluche The second argument is the condition, if it is empty, you will end up having nothing to compare the value of `\language` with. Please look at the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) for more details.